# Mysql - Replication of multiple database

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm trying to do a redudancy with Mysql.
I'm making master-master.
I'm very happy because it works with one database. When I add something in a table, it's added on the table of the second server. The 2 DB are NOT on the same server. 
 but I want to add other database.

So, I add this to both server:

```
replicate-do-db = other
binlog-do-db = other
```

I restarted mysql, but the result of "show master status" is the same (specially "Binlog_Do_DB" (and the database isn't in both server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the filters you placed in the my.cnf file, so you could replicate all the changes you did in all databases

Comment: So, you mean that I must to remove 'replicate-do-db' and 'binlog-do-db' ?

Comment: Hi, of course, you should to do that for you can replicate every thing you change in anywhere database exists in your database server

Comment: Thanks you, it works ! I just to precise (to other people) that I have got some problems with slave status (some command that want to be executed, but they will failed). To fix it: 'stop slave', 'reset slave', 'reset master', 'start slave' (on both)

Answer (score 1):

A mini-lesson in replicate/binlog-do/ignore-db:

Without any of the replicate or binlog do or ignore commands in my.cnf, all writes are replicated.

The sender (Master) can filter what is sent by using `binlog_*` command(s).

The receiver (Slave) can filter what is applied by using `replicate_*`.

List multiple commands to specify multiple dbs/tables (I think).

Master-Master means that both servers act as both a sender and a receiver, so it makes sense for both machines to have both commands.

In a simple Master-Slave setup, It is usually redundant to say both binlog and replicate.

The `do` commands, you say what *not* to filter; the `ignore` commands say what *is* filtered out.  Don't use both; else I'll have to send you to a complicated flowchart somewhere in the documentation.